# Is there any time limit for flag review?

Tags: support, flags, review

My question is: Is there any time limit to have a flag approved / rejected? If "NO", then why we don't have such a time limit? What happens to the flags that remain unreviewed?

Comment: I have response to my flag at most after 7-8 days.

Comment: Some reviews take longer than others and I've noticed that some mods don't mark the flag one way or the other until they finish deciding / performing actions which can take several days.  Is this really causing a problem to you?  Do we really need to impose and SLA on the Moderators, who for the most part are giving up their own time and will eventually review all of the flags?

Comment: I suspect some complex flags are intentionally left around in the queue as a "TODO" style reminder. Some flags are more urgent than others too.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your replies. Let me clear one thing: This question is purely a question & not a "complain". I asked this question as one my flags got approved after more than 15 days. So I just wanted to know if we have some rule for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All moderators see a counter of active flags on every page of the site, so they are constantly reminded how many flags are still unhandled.

There is no hard rule for how long it will take until a flag is handled. Most flags can be quickly handled when a moderator is available, stuff like spam should be gone quickly. The actual time depends heavily on the number and activity of mods, their time zones and the amount of community moderation.

Some flags take more time to investigate or come to a decision, moderators might keep them in the queue to remind them of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Usually within a day receive responses to flags. (depend on availability of moderators).**

I have once response to my flag at most after 8 days. Sometimes it take time to get responses to flags. May be many moderators on vacation or discussion needed on flag.

This would be great if there can be documentation how much maximum time will it take to respond flags. But we can't force them to have it. Because they are giving their own time to react on flags and decision needs to be perfect.